# Use recursion on array of integers

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

Write a function that by given array of integers, and a positive number X, returns
the product of all odd elements that are greater than X. Use recursion!

I tried this:

```
function result(arr, x) {
    if (arr.length <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (arr[0] > x && arr[0] % 2 === 1) {
        return arr[0] + result(arr.slice(1));
    }

    return result(arr.slice(1));
}

console.log(result([3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 1));
```

And the answer is 3.
After the first iteration (x becomes undefined).

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. This community is here for helping not for making your task.

Comment: please add this to the question along with the error.

Comment: product != sum, otherwise looks.good already. And please [edit] that into the question.

Comment: Concerning x becoming undefined: when you do the call, pass x on: `result(..., x)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
function result(arr, x) {
    if (arr.length <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (arr[0] > x && arr[0] % 2 === 1) {
        return arr[0] + result(arr.slice(1), x);
    }

    return result(arr.slice(1), x);
}

console.log(result([3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 1));
```

You were very close! You only needed to pass the value of `x` into the `result` function when calling it again. After that, it returns the correct answer: *3 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 = 27*

---

EDIT: `x` needs to be passed into the function call each time because of the scope of the variables. So far, the `result` function only knows about the variables passed directly into it.

If `x` is a constant, another way to deal with that would be to define `x` at the beginning and then change the function to only accept the array:

```
    const x = 1;

    function result(arr) {
        if (arr.length <= 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (arr[0] > x && arr[0] % 2 === 1) {
            return arr[0] + result(arr.slice(1));
        }

        return result(arr.slice(1));
    }

    console.log(result([3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]));
```

If `x` is not a constant, but you only want to pass the value into a recursive function once, you can do that too with a sub-function, e.g.:

```
    function result(arr, x) {
      function recur(arr) {
        if (arr.length <= 0) {
          return 0;
        }

        if (arr[0] > x && arr[0] % 2 === 1) {
          return arr[0] + recur(arr.slice(1));
        }

        return recur(arr.slice(1));
      }

      return recur(arr);
    }

    console.log(result([3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 1));
```

In this case, the `recur` function can access the variables passed directly into it (`arr`) as well as the variables of its parent function (`x`). The value of `arr` of the closest available scope is used. This method can be helpful in simplifying complicated recursive functions.

Comment: You're welcome :) I'm glad it worked for you. I've edited the answer to try and explain it and to show how you could change the function so that you don't need to pass the value of `x` each time.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to calculate the *sum*. The *product* of the odd numbers from `[3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` > 1 would imho be: 3 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 9 (= 2835). Here's a snippet that filters out the odd numbers > 1 first, than uses a recursive (sub) function to calculate the product. The use of the sub function is an [optimization](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/javascript-optimizations-tail-call-optimization-tco-471b4f8e4f37). You can also use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) btw.

```js
function productOfUnEvenValuesGreaterThanX(arr, x) {
    // filter desired values
    const oddAndGreaterThanX = arr.filter(v => v > x && ~~(v % 2));
    //                                                  ^ bitwise to determine odd 
    
    // calculate the product recursively
    function product(arrx, y) {
      return arrx.length 
        ? product(arrx.slice(1), (arrx.shift() || 1) * y)
        : y;
    }
    
    return !oddAndGreaterThanX.length ? 0 : product(oddAndGreaterThanX, x);
}

console.log(productOfUnEvenValuesGreaterThanX([3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 1));
console.log(productOfUnEvenValuesGreaterThanX([2, 4, 6, 8], 1));

// alternatively you can use a reducer
function productOfUnEvenValuesGreaterThanXReducer(arr, x) {
  return arr.reduce( (acc, val) =>
    val > x && ~~(val % 2) 
      ? (acc || 1) * val 
      : acc, 0 );
}

console.log(productOfUnEvenValuesGreaterThanXReducer([3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 1));
console.log(productOfUnEvenValuesGreaterThanXReducer([2, 4, 6, 8], 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another recursive approach without mutating the array.

```js
function sumResult(arr, x, i = 0, sum = 0) {
  if ([0, i].includes(arr.length)) {
    return sum;
  }

  const updated = sum + (arr[i] > x && arr[i] % 2 === 1 ? arr[i] : 0);

  return sumResult(arr, x, i + 1, updated);
}

console.log('sum: ', sumResult([3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 1));




function productResult(arr, x, i = 0, product = 1) {
  if ([0, i].includes(arr.length)) {
    return product;
  }

  const updated = product * (arr[i] > x && arr[i] % 2 === 1 ? arr[i] : 1);

  return productResult(arr, x, i + 1, updated);
}

console.log('product: ', productResult([3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 1));
```